# Default Tokens With a Values Replace It When New Values Received

Tags: html, xml, token, splunk

currently i facing an issues which need initialize my token as any value 1st. However the token values will change when a new values received. Below is my code:

```
<form>
      <init>
        <set token="CH1_CHW_FLOW">0</set>     
      </init>        
</form>

<search id="header">
<query>index="rtindex" Label="CH1" Order="12" |eval Value=round(Value,3) |stats latest(Value) as Value by ID2 |rename ID2 as Label | untable Label field name | xyseries field Label name</query>
<earliest>@d</earliest>
<latest>now</latest>
<preview>
  <set token="FLOW_LPS">$result.CH1_CHW_FLOW_LPS$</set>
  <set token="FLOW">$result.CH1_CHW_FLOW$</set>
  <set token="COOLING_LOAD">$result.CH1_COOLING_LOAD$</set>
  <set token="EFF">$result.CH1_EFF$</set>
</preview>
```

```
<table id="Chiller_1" border="1px solid black"> 
      <tr><th>HEADER Details </th><th>Values</th></tr>
       <tr><td>CHWF (USGPM)</td><td>$CH1_CHW_FLOW$</td></tr> 
       <tr><td>FLOW (LPS)</td><td>$CH1_CHW_FLOW_LPS$</td></tr>
       <tr><td>COOLING LOAD</td><td>$CH1_COOLING_LOAD$</td></tr>  
       <tr><td>KW/Ton</td><td>$CH1_EFF$</td></tr> 
 </table>
```

However due to unknow reason i fail to initialize the value as Zero. It show me 
$result.CH1_CHW_FLOW$ instead of zero. Please advise. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The way to resolve it used eval:
 if(isnull($result.fieldname$),0,$result.fieldname$)